# Как разбиваются данные на куски в протоколе TCP/IP?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip

Привет.

Изучаю сети. Не понимаю момент про размер кусков (сегмент, пакет, кадр), которые создаются для передачи кадра по сети. Например, *tcp*-сегмент при использовании технологии передачи *ethernet2* может быть максимально 1500 байт. то есть, с прикладного уровня пришли данные с заголовком *http* (например, веб-сервер отдал документ хтмл), эти данные разбились на куски-сегменты по 1500 байт. потом [заголовок *tcp* + сегмент] с транспортного уровня передается уровню *ip*. написано, что максимальный размер пакета уровня *ip* = 65535 байт. Не понимаю - **идет разбиение на куски по 1500 байт на транспортном уровне, зачем указан размер 65535 байт, если передаваемые куски имеют размер 1500 байт**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Эталонная модель** — это идеальная модель передачи данных. OSI помогает иллюстрировать зависимость
>   одних протоколов от других, и кто кем погоняет, но она не может
>   диктовать, как им функционировать.

### MTU и модель OSI

Протоколы транспортного уровня (протоколы TCP или UDP), пользующиеся сетевым уровнем для отправки пакетов, считают, **что максимальный размер поля данных IP-пакета равен 65535**, и поэтому могут передать ему сообщение такой длины для транспортировки. В функции уровня **IP входит разбиение слишком длинного для конкретного типа составляющей сети сообщения на более короткие пакеты** с созданием соответствующих служебных полей, нужных для последующей сборки фрагментов в исходное сообщение.

В большинстве типов локальных и глобальных сетей определяется такое понятие как максимальный размер поля данных кадра или пакета, в которые должен инкапсулировать свой пакет протокол IP. Эту величину обычно называют максимальной единицей транспортировки - Maximum Transfer Unit, MTU. Сети Ethernet имеют значение MTU, равное 1500 байт, сети FDDI - 4096 байт, а сети Х.25 чаще всего работают с MTU в 128 байт.

**MTU является характеристикой канального уровня модели OSI.** Если IP хочет отослать датаграмму, которая больше чем MTU канального уровня, осуществляется фрагментация (fragmentation), при этом датаграмма разбивается на меньшие части (фрагменты). Каждый фрагмент должен быть меньше чем MTU.

**Верхний уровень всегда знает о нижнем**. Когда IP уровень получает IP датаграмму, которую необходимо отправить, он определяет, на какой локальный интерфейс отправляется датаграмма (или маршрутизируется), и **запрашивает интерфейс, чтобы тот сообщил размер своего MTU.** IP сравнивает MTU с размером датаграммы и, если необходимо, осуществляет фрагментацию. Фрагментация может быть осуществлена как на отправляющем хосте, так и на промежуточном маршрутизаторе.

Теоретически, максимальный размер IP-дейтаграммы составляет 65 535 байтов, что обусловлено 16-разрядным полем полной длины в IP-заголовке.

**Вам пользователь @Smithson сообщил правильный ответ, ведь IP работает не только над Ethernet, в каждой сети свой размер.**

### Зачем нужен MTU?

Когда общаются два компьютера в одной и той же сети, важным является MTU для этой сети. Однако, когда общаются два компьютера в разных сетях, каждый промежуточный канал может иметь различные MTU. В данном случае важным является не MTU двух сетей, к которым подключены компьютеры, а наименьший MTU любого канала данных, находящегося между двумя компьютерами. Он называется транспортным MTU (path MTU).

Транспортный MTU между любыми двумя хостами может быть не постоянным. MTU зависит от загруженности канала на настоящий момент. Также он зависит от маршрута. Маршрут может быть несимметричным (маршрут от A до B может быть совсем не тем, что маршрут от B к A), поэтому MTU может быть неодинаков для этих двух направлений.

### У протокола TCP есть MSS

Есть такое понятие, как максимальный Размер TCP Сегмента (MSS), который определяет максимальное количество данных, которые хост желает принимать в единственной TCP/IP датаграмме.

**Мало того, эта TCP/IP датаграмма может быть фрагментирована в уровне IP.**

Значение MSS посылают как опцию TCP заголовка только в сегменте TCP SYN. Каждая сторона на TCP соединении сообщает свое значение MSS другой стороне. Хост отправитель обязан ограничивать размер данных в единственном TCP сегменте в значение, меньшем или равном MSS, о котором сообщает хост получатель.

**Механизм работы MSS следующий:** при создании TCP соединения, машина определяет размер буфера исходящего интерфейса и MTU этого интерфейса. Дальше эти два числа сравниваются и выбирается наименьшее. Тут следует оговориться, что за MTU выбирается число по формуле MTU минус 40 байт, для учета TCP и IP заголовков. Затем выбранное число сравнивается с размером MSS, переданным принимающей стороной, и снова выберется наименьшее значение.
Пример работы MSS:

1. Машина А сравнивает размер своего буфера интерфейса (16 Кбайт) со значение MTU этого интерфейса (1500-40 = 1460 байт) и использует наименьшее число как MSS при отправке к машине B.
2. Машина B принимает значение MSS машины A (1460) и сравнивает его со значением MTU своего исходящего интерфейса (4462 — 40 = 4422 байт).
3. Машина B выбирает наименьшее из получившихся значений (1460) как значение MSS при отправке TCP сегментов к машине A.
4. Машина B сравнивает размер своего буфера интерфейса (8 Кбайт) со значение MTU этого интерфейса (4462-40 = 4422 байт) и использует наименьшее число как MSS при отправке к машине A.
5. Машина A принимает значение MSS машины B (4422) и сравнивает его со значение MTU своего исходящего интерфейса (1500 — 40 = 1460 байт).
6. Машина A выбирает наименьшее из получившихся значений (1460) как значение MSS при отправке TCP сегментов к машине B.

Таким образом MSS на обеих сторонах установлено равным 1460 байтам, это наиболее частая ситуация.

Answer (score 5):

Затем, что по ip работает не только tcp, но и udp, и icmp.
У каждого протокола свой предел.

А сети бывают не только ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

> Например, tcp-сегмент при использовании технологии передачи ethernet2 может быть максимально 1500 байт

Проблемы начинаются где-то здесь. 1 500 — это вполне стандартный размер *пакета* (любого протокола сетевого уровня, не обязательно АйПи), который умещается в езернетный *кадр*. Длина *сегмента* ТиСиПи ещё меньше, вполне обычным значением является 1 460, как раз для того, чтобы конечный *пакет* (с заголовками ТиСиПи и АйПи),  мог уложиться в 1 500 *октетов*. Стандартный размер, если не согласовано иное, и вовсе 536 (как указано в [разделе 4.2.2.6 РФЦ 1122](http://rfc2.ru/1122.rfc/print#p4.2), жаль что нет перевода [РФЦ 6691 (англ)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6691)).

В принципе, размер сегмента выбирается сетевым стеком ОС, как раз таки с учётом максимальных параметров передачи, потому как и в Езернет может пролазить 9 000 октетов, и не только Езернет бывает в этом мире.

> **идет разбиение на куски по 1500 байт на транспортном уровне, зачем указан размер 65535 байт, если передаваемые куски имеют размер 1500 байт?**

Это же *максимальный* размер. Максимальный размер сегмента ТиСиПи равен [тому же самому значению](http://rfc2.ru/793.rfc/print#p3.1), кстати говоря, поскольку в обоих случаях используются поля по 16 бит. И если смотреть совсем строго, то сегмент ТиСиПи максимального размера вообще невозможно отправить по протоколу АйПи! Как так получилось? Да просто решили, что 16 бит хватит и тут, и там. Что характерно, не ошиблись, хватает с запасом.

Важно понимать, что вся матрёшка слоёв сетевого стека изначально задумана для жёсткого разделения решаемых в разных слоях вопросов и принципиально подразумевает независимость протоколов разного уровня. И при возникновении подобных вопросов, первое о чём имеет смысл задуматься, это что будет, если вместо протокола А на каком-то уровне будет использоваться неведомый протокол Б. Поэтому, теоретические ограничения на каждом из уровней свои и согласование реальных параметров идёт уже исходя из реальных условий. Например, для АйПи поверх Инфинибэнда типично ограничение по размеру пакета в 2 044 октета (размер сегмента ТиСиПи предлагаю посчитать самостоятельно).

Но ещё интереснее то, как вроде бы недостижимые на проводе максимумы иногда находят неожиданное применение. Например, даже несмотря на то, что в Езернет больше 9 000 не пролазит, вполне реалистично получить пакет длиной около 64К, содержащий внутри сегмент ТиСиПи со столь же близким к 64К значением! Всё за счёт аппаратного (иногда драйверного) ускорения получения данных (для десятигигабитной сети явление повсеместное) — карта снимает с провода набор пакетов "нормальной" длины для одного соединения и переупаковывает их в один такой мега-пакет. В результате, ОС вообще не видит изначального "горошка", для неё пришёл один пакет длиной 64К, с ним она дальше и будет работать. Может и наружу такой же мега-пакет отправить, а реальную сегментацию до нужной длины выполнит уже сетевая карта.

Примером же практически естественного использования МТУ в 64К является интерфейс обратной петли, по умолчанию в Линуксах на нём именно такой МТУ (причём его до 2ГБ можно увеличивать! только это уже как раз бесполезно для рядовых протоколов верхних уровней), и именно на такие куски будет биться тисипишный поток, упаковываясь по дороге в айпишные пакетики (плюс-минус накладные расходы на заголовки).