# Какая разница между понятием "селектор" и "фильтр" в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Привет.

Не понимаю разницу между понятием "селектор" и "фильтр". В некоторых учебных  материалах этапы обучения джейквери называются, например, 1. Выборка 2. Фильтры. Например, пишут, что *:first* - это фильтр. По-моему, это просто псевдоэлемент, который придумали при написании джейквери.

Не понимаю правил комбинирования селекторов. Какие-то есть правила, как написать сложный селектор? Можно ли использовать несколько псевдоэлементов сразу, например, *p.class:first-child:first:visible*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Стандарты W3C

**Селекторы** - это **критерии** для выборки определенного элемента со страницы, набор селекторов и их комбинирование называется шаблоном. Есть множество селекторов -  это селекторы атрибутов, селекторы классов, псевдо-классы, псевдо-элементы и т.д.

[W3C говорит](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html):

> Эти шаблоны, называемые селекторами, могут изменяться в диапазоне от
>   простых имен элементов до сложных текстовых структур. Если
>   определенный элемент удовлетворяет всем критериям, устанавливаемым
>   шаблоном, то соответствующий селектор сопоставляется данному элементу.

### Упрощенная терминология

Часто для упрощения, при написании шаблона на выборку, говорят так, что есть **селектор**, которым называют выборку по элементам (.class например) и есть **фильтры**, последним, для удобства, называют **совокупность** псевдо-классов или псевдо-элементов: **$(селектор:фильтры)**.

> **Селекторы** - строчные выражения, с помощью которых задаются условия поиска элементов DOM на странице (.className, #id, ..)
>
> **Фильтры** - это строчные выражения с помощью которых можно уточнить результат других селекторов (:first, :last, ...)

### Комбинирование

Комбинирование нескольких фильтров возможно и ваш пример будет работать, попробуем **перевести его на русский**: выбрать элементы p с классом "class" которые являются первыми в своих родительских элементах, взять первый подобный элемент, после чего проверить что он виден на странице и вернуть его, если это так.

**Более адекватный пример:** $('#results:odd:has('img')'). В данном случае мы выбираем все нечетные элементы с id="results", которые содержат элементы img, то есть изображения.

### Полезная информация

[Читаем вот здесь](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) про существующие селекторы, [вот здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=682) про их комбинирование.

Comment: прочитал в твоем профиле, что ты спец по информационной безопасности. у меня еще есть вопрос по сетям (я задал его ОТДЕЛЬНЫМ вопросом) - по разбиению кусков пересылаемой по сети информации. как протокол TCP понимает, что надо разбивать данные на куски по 1460 байт при пересылке через Ethernet|| ? ведь уровень TCP ничего не знает о нижележащих уровнях стека TCP/IP

Comment: @Dimon Вы немного путаете :) По иерархии, верхний уровень знает все о нижнем уровне и имеет право к нему обращаться, а нижний уровень ничего не знает про верхний уровень. Я отвечу на ваш вопрос в самом вопросе, немного позже :)

Comment: @Dimon http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572167/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-tcp-ip ответил на ваш вопрос, в кратце IP перед фрагментацией запрашивает максимальный размер у интерфейса и благодаря этому делит дейтаграмму.

Comment: спасибо. сейчас почитаю и плюсик поставлю)

Answer (score 2):

Термин "фильтр" не совсем корректен применительно к селектору. Но отфильтровать список можно селектором.
То есть селектор - это определитель множества:

```
#wow p > .class:first-child
```

А фильтр (или фильтрация) - это операция отсеивания множества, которая может быть сделана по селектору:

```
$('div').filter('.red:visible');
```

> Можно ли использовать несколько псевдоэлементов сразу, например, p.class:first-child:first:visible...

А вот тут терминология неверная - не псевдоэлемент, а псевдокласс. Можно, только `:first` и `:visible` - это не css, это псевдоклассы, которые работают только в выборках jQuery . Псевдоэлементы - это только `:after` и `:before` .

Comment: `А фильтр (или фильтрация) - это операция отсеивания множества, которая может быть сделана по селектору.`

Правильнее сказать не отсеивание множества, а отсеивание элементов множества по параметру фильтра.

Answer (score 2):

1. Фильтр может использоватся когда надо найти из опредленного множества какойто элемент.
2. Селектор может использоваться вместе с фильтром, с помощью селектора можно задать множество и профильтровать то что надо из этого множества.